# how to add values over each bar in stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
similarity_score_summary={'sim_model':['jaccard_sim','Cos_tfidf_sim','spacy_sim','sent_trf_sim','wv_gensim_sim'],
                          'acc(thres=0.5)':[0.65,0.66,0.38,0.62,0.39],
                          'acc(thres=0.75)':[0.61,0.62,0.41,0.79,0.44],
                          'acc(thres=0.90)':[0.62,0.62,0.60,0.76,0.55]
                }

df_sim = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(similarity_score_summary)
# setting first name as index column 
df_sim.set_index("sim_model", inplace = True) 

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
axes=fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
bar_width = 0.3
idx = np.array(range(df_sim.shape[0]))
labels = df_sim.index
plt.bar(data=df_sim, height='acc(thres=0.5)', x=idx, color='b', width=bar_width, label='acc(thres=0.5)')
plt.bar(data=df_sim, height='acc(thres=0.75)', x=idx+bar_width, color='g', width=bar_width, label='acc(thres=0.75)')
plt.bar(data=df_sim, height='acc(thres=0.90)', x=idx+bar_width+bar_width, color='magenta', width=bar_width, label='acc(thres=0.90)')
plt.xticks(idx, labels, rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Similarity methods')
plt.ylabel('Similarity Score')
plt.ylim((0, 1))
plt.title('Accuracy score for different Similarity methods on Quora Question pairs Kaggle data')
plt.legend(['thres=0.5', 'thres=0.75', 'thres=0.9'], loc='upper right', ncol = 3)
plt.show()
```

This results in below fig:

[image]

I need to add values on top of each bar. Need help?

Comment: There are a number of issues with this implementation, including that you created `axes` and then didn't correctly use the object (e.g. `axes.bar(...)` instead of `plt.bar(...)`). The correct current way to add annotations is with: `for c in axes.containers: axes.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f', label_type='edge', padding=1)`

Comment: The correct way to do this is plot `df_sim` directly which reduces the plot and annotation code to only 6 lines (compared to 25 shown in the accepted answer): see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToWH1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define bars, iterate over them and get height of each bar, get `x` value and use `plt.text` to add value above each bar.

Example:

```py
bar1 = plt.bar(
    data=df_sim,
    height="acc(thres=0.5)",
    x=idx,
    color="b",
    width=bar_width,
    label="acc(thres=0.5)",
)
bar2 = plt.bar(
    data=df_sim,
    height="acc(thres=0.75)",
    x=idx + bar_width,
    color="g",
    width=bar_width,
    label="acc(thres=0.75)",
)
bar3 = plt.bar(
    data=df_sim,
    height="acc(thres=0.90)",
    x=idx + bar_width + bar_width,
    color="magenta",
    width=bar_width,
    label="acc(thres=0.90)",
)
for bars in [bar1, bar2, bar3]:
    for bar in bars:
        yval = bar.get_height()
        plt.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2.0, yval + 0.005, yval, ha="center")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanx. This works.Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: @Nishant You're welcome! I'm glad I helped. Not sure, to add text to an image you have to know the coordinates, and to know coordinates you have to iterate over each bar since each bar has different X,Y coordinates. Maybe there is, but I'm not aware.

Comment: Thanx. One more thing. Can we center the xticks?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, answer updated.